# Adding object on controller AFRAME Magic leap

Tags: javascript, augmented-reality, aframe

Does anyone know how we can add an entity to the controller? ( Say a gun on the controller) in Aframe for the magic leap?

Currently, I am attaching things directly by using
`<a-entity magic leap-controls="hand: right" controller-tracking>` and putting entities in it.

However, this is causing a problem i.e., the entity doesn't stay on the controller consistently as it moves i.e. Rotating it makes it get offset by a certain amount (it looks closer to the user than the real controller). Does anyone know how to fix this?